# retrofit get boolean from mysql

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, retrofit2

I have a problem with retrofit in my android app (java) retrieving a boolean field from php/mysql webservice.

In my java model, I have a boolean field `selected`, declared as:

```
@SerializedName("selected")
@Expose
private boolean selected;
```

In my MySQL database, the field is declared as TINYINT

When I upload my object, it is correctly saved in the database (0 or 1).

But when I want to download the same object, I get an error:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
> Expected a boolean but was NUMBER at line 11 column 22 path
> $[0].selected

php code:

```
<?php
    header('content-type:application/json');
    if (isset($_GET['deviceName']) && $_GET['deviceName'] != "") {
        $deviceName = $_GET['deviceName'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `ComList` WHERE deviceName = '$deviceName' ORDER BY clistId, ord, categOrd ASC;";

        $pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
        $pdo_options[PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND] = 'SET NAMES utf8';
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bdd', 'user', 'password', $pdo_options);
        $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES, false);
        $response = $bdd->query($sql);
        $output = $response->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo(json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
?>
```

I can't modify the type of the field in the java model.

Any idea please?
Something to modify in the SQL request?
Modify the output in PHP?

The only way I found that give a good result is:

```
$output = $response->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$tab = array();
foreach($output AS $value) {
    $value['selected'] = $value['selected'] ? true : false;
    array_push($tab, $value);
}
echo(json_encode($tab, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

But I think it's such a dirty process.

Comment: In MySQL there is no BOOLEAN datatype, it is an alias of TINYINT(1), and it does not provide any constraint to the value. https://dbfiddle.uk/pkUw5onV You may try to use `SELECT !!boolean_column ..` - maybe this will help. If not then you'd define this column as numeric in your model.

Comment: @Akina As I wrote, impossible to change type. And I already know there isn't boolean type in mysql. I didn't ask why it happens but how to do other way.

Comment: *As I wrote, impossible to change type* In the model? you cannot alter in the database - this is clear.. but in your application you cannot do this too?

Comment: @Akina _"I can't modify the type of the field in the java model."_ because it's linked to a local Room database too. I can't, and/or I don't want, to modify the model.

Comment: If you can do nothing then your problem seems to be not solvable...

Comment: Not really, I added a (dirty) solution, so no "not solvable". Maybe someone else could have another idea. That's why I ask here... But not you, I understood.